# javascript: компактная запись поиска нескольких значений в массиве

Tags: javascript, строки, оптимизация, поиск, indexof

Вопрос из серии - можно ли записать компактно следующую запись

```
var sortState = 0;

sortState = (classes.indexOf('sort-unknown') !== -1) ? 0 : sortState;
sortState = (classes.indexOf('sort-up') !== -1) ? 1 : sortState;
sortState = (classes.indexOf('sort-down') !== -1) ? 2 : sortState;
```

В `classes` содержатся названия классов через пробел (если всё правильно, то среди названий классов только один из приведённых выше).

Например, запись, где требуется выбрать одно из трех значений в зависимости от значения `sortState` я записал компактно и понятно (как мне кажется)

```
$(this).addClass((['sort-unknown', 'sort-up', 'sort-down'])[sortState]);
```

Вот интересует, можно ли сделать тоже самое с приведённым в начале кодом, чтобы не писать многострочные конструкции.

Comment: Можно. Уберите первую из трех строчек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var sortInfos = [
  { class: "sort-unknown", state: 0 },
  { class: "sort-up", state: 1 },
  { class: "sort-down", state: 2 }
];

var classes = "aaa sort-up bbb";

var sortState = 0;
sortInfos.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
  if (classes.indexOf(item.class) !== -1) {
    sortState = item.state;
  }
});

console.log(sortState);
```

Comment: это конечно универсальный код и подходит для случая, когда очень много состояний

Comment: @Zhihar я пишу только универсальный код :)

Comment: @Igor, а что бы не отходить от изначальной концепции и уже имеющегося массив (`['sort-unknown', 'sort-up', 'sort-down']`) который где-то ещё используется можно использовать индекс, а не переделывать массив заполняя его объектами ;)

Comment: @MedvedevDev тем более, что в полном списке параметров колбэка в `forEach` есть индекс

Comment: @Igor, О чем и речь. Ещё с точки зрения оптимизации не мешало бы брейкнуть, ну так, что бы лишних проходов не делать

Answer (score 0):

Есть чуть изменить код @Igor, убрав немного универсальности

```
var sortState = 0;
["sort-unknown", "sort-up", "sort-down"].forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
    if (classes.indexOf(item) !== -1)
        sortState = index;
});
```

Но для трех строк избыточно, хотя и удобно.
Может можно что-то ещё сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Ну и немного ES6 магии пусть будет:

```js
let sortState = 0;
const arr = [ 'sort-unknown', 'sort-up', 'sort-down' ];
const classes = 'aaa sort-up bbb';

const findIndex = arr.findIndex(item => classes.indexOf(item) >= 0);

sortState = findIndex >= 0 ? findIndex : sortState;

console.log(sortState);
```

Answer (score 0):

@MedvedevDev, тогда уж еще чуть подчистить

```
const findIndex = ['sort-unknown', 'sort-up', 'sort-down'].findIndex(item => classes.indexOf(item) >= 0);

let sortState = (findIndex >= 0) ? findIndex : 0;
```

вот только вопрос - насколько использование ES6 целесообразно, много ли народу ещё пользуется IE11?

Comment: Это не совсем чистка.Переменные которые у меня вынесены отдельно используются ещё где-то, судя по тому коду что в вопросе. ES6 использовать целесообразно чуть более чем полностью, но естественно вкупе с использованием babel.

Comment: ох уж этот babel и прочие модули - когда вижу `npm install` - несколько теряюсь, надо будет в этом всём разобраться и понять можно ли написать на ES6, подключить через `<script>` тот же babel и забыть про несовместимость со старыми браузерами

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример, если я правильно вас понял.

```js
    var classes_0 = ['sort-unknown', 'sort-up', 'sort-down']
    var classes_1 = 'sort-unknown sort-up sort-down'
 
/* 
// -------------------  
1. Объявляем метод  который определяет наличие нужного вхождения и
 его положение в участке  
---------------//*/

/* 
      метод "Есть ли в _param входящее _name", для строк можно указать разделитель _marker
*/
    function isThere(_param, _name, _marker){     
/*
      разделяем старку на два участка, по разделителю _name 
     // если разделителя нет вернёт 0-ой массив
*/
     var param_ = _param.toString().split(_name)
/*
      если  массив  0-ой то и делать нечего не надо
*/
     if(param_.length-1){ 
/*
   возвращаем  результат
*/
      return [{ 
/*
   для строки
*/
       "string": function(){return arguments[0].split((_marker || " ")).length-1}, 
/*
   для массива
*/
       "object": function(){return arguments[0].split(",").length-1}
/*
   выбираем метод от того какой пришёл тип _param
*/ 
      }[typeof(_param)](param_[0]), true] 
     }
     return [0, false] 
    }
/*
// проста нативная проверка метода 
// тестим со строкой и массивом
 console.log(isThere(classes_0, 'sort-unknown'))
 console.log(isThere(classes_0, 'sortRRp'))
 console.log(isThere(classes_1, 'sort-up'))
 console.log(isThere(classes_1, 'sorFvp'))
*/

/* // ------------------- 
2. собираем Метод перебора 
---------------//*/

/*
   метод "Есть тут кто"  -- Метод конструктора  вызывается в контексте объекта --- 
*/
    function ThereIsWho(_param, _marker){ 
     var return_ = []
 /*
   запускаем цикл WHILE -- пока _param имеет длину --
*/
     while(_param.length){
/*
 внутренняя инструкция перезаписывает возвращаемое значение,
 если найдено искомое вхождение

 // можно проще, но сделал как-то так 

*/
      (function(){ 
       if(arguments[1]){ 
        this[0] = arguments[0]
       }
      }).apply(return_, isThere(this, _param.shift(), _marker))
     }
     return +return_.toString() // хардкор к намбер
    }

/*
    // ThereIsWho 
    // для массива -- просто вызываем в контексте массива
     console.log(ThereIsWho.call(classes_0, ['sort-unknown', 'sort-up', 'sort-down']))
    // для строки -- для вызова в контексте необходимо перевести старку к массиву  
    // для простоты сразу разделил по маркеру ( пробел)
     console.log(ThereIsWho.call(classes_1.split(" "), ['sort-unknown', 'sort-up', 'sort-down']))
    */

/* // -------------------  
3.  а для того чтобы чтобы не писать много строчные конструкции.
 ---------------//*/ 

/*
  присваиваем конструктору Array свой метод
*/
    Array.prototype["_addClass_"] = function(_that){
     return ThereIsWho.call(this, _that.slice())
    }
/*
  присваиваем конструктору String свой метод
*/
    String.prototype["_addClass_"] = function(_param, _marker){ 
/*
   String не может открыто вызывать методы Array 
*/
     return Array.prototype.join.call(this, "") 
/*
     создаём массив согласно маркеру
*/
      .split(_marker) 
 /*
     вызываем метод конструктора Array 
 */ 
      ._addClass_(_param) 
    }

// вызываем на массиве

    console.log(classes_0._addClass_(['sortunknown', 'sort-up', 'sortdown']))

// вызываем на строке

    console.log(classes_1._addClass_(['sort-unknown', 'sortup', 'sortdown'], " "))

// ещё вариант вызова на строке

    console.log('sort-unknown sort-up sort-down'._addClass_(['sort-unknown', 'sor-tup', 'sort-down'], " "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю построить хеш-таблицу из массива, тогда поиск будет элементарен:

```
var classes = ['sorted', 'sort-down'];
var classHash = classes.reduce(function(acc, c){
  acc[c] = true;
  return acc;
}, {});

switch (true) {
  case classHash['sort-up']: sortState = 1; break;
  case classHash['sort-down']: sortState = 2; break;
  default:
  case classHash['sort-unknown']: sortState = 0; break;
}
```

Можно пойти другим путём и создать карту значений заранее:

```js
var sortMap = {
  'sort-unknown': 0,
  'sort-up': 1,
  'sort-down': 2
}
// ...
var classes = 'sorted sort-down'.split(' ');
var index = classes.findIndex(function(c) {
  return c in sortMap;
});
var sortState = ~index ? sortMap[classes[index]] : sortMap['sort-unknown'];
console.log(sortState); // 2
```